# Nokogiri will not print, nothing returned from page.css

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I wrote this script on an ubuntu machine, have recently just started using a chromebook on the beta channel and tried to use the same script with the same html file however nokogiri just returns nothing.

I've tried:
Using the same version of Ruby (2.3.1) as originally used (on the Linux machine).
Reinstalling Nokogiri after changing over to 2.3.1

```
require "nokogiri"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("prods.html"))
puts page.class #Nokogiri::HTML::Document

d = page.css("//div/[@class='ember-view']/div[@class='well']/h3/a")
lines = d.map(&:text).join("\n")
puts lines
```

This just lists products available on a rails site from a local html file.
When using it on the Chromebook it will return the "page.class" but nothing is returned from "page.css" and when checking with pry "d" is empty.

Comment: What does the specific model of the Chromebook have to do with this? Is the specific model so important that it needs to be in the title?

Comment: I've retitled this to try and focus on the problem, not the computer that happened to be involved, or the weather where you were, or what you had for lunch...

Comment: given the "ember" portion is client side js loading the data dynamically? If so you will have to switch to something like `mechanize`, or `selenium`

Comment: You're using page.css and passing xpath. either pass css or use page.xpath

Comment: I tried page.xpath to no avail, I guess mechanize might be the way to go, I'm just still bewildered as to why it will work on one machine but not the other.

Comment: @engineersmnky The file has been downloaded locally, and from what I can tell I'm using the css method correctly.
Like I said, this code works on my work *nix machine.

Comment: @Hobnob without seeing the source file that you are parsing it is very difficult to help you parse the file however the comment below mine has an extremely valid point. did you try changing `css` to `xpath` or using css selectors because what you have right now is not valid css?

Comment: @engineersmnky I have just managed to fix this yesterday, not entirely sure what was causing it as I only reinstalled ruby and re-cloned my repo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reinstalled ruby and re-cloned my repo

Comment: You could just delete the question instead of leaving this non-answer